# Get screen resolution from site visitors

Tags: logging, screen-resolution

Is there any way to capture the screen resolution of site visitors through server logs?  Or do I need to track the visitor information through some programmatic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen resolution isn't sent by the browser as part of the standard request headers, so yes, you'll need to do something with Javascript to send this data where you want it.  If you're looking for an existing "product", Google Analytics handles this data collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Google analytics, they track this.
   or
2. Write it on your own.